# How to concat two tensor with dynamic shape in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have two tensor I want to concat in tensorflow.

So the shape of these tensor are :`(Bs,dynamics,n_features)`

The `batch_size` and `n_features` are guarantee to be same, so I think this operation is possible.

However, I think tensorflow will run a pre-check?  tensorflow will check if two tensor with shape `(None, None, n_features)` could be concatenated in axis 1, which is not possible, because it doesn't know what is the result of `None+None`

Anybody has any idea to this?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating should not be a problem in your case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.random.normal((5, 10, 20))
x2 = tf.random.normal((5, 33, 20))

@tf.function
def concatenate(x1, x2):
  return tf.concat([x1, x2], axis=1)

concatenate(x1, x2).shape
```